# Convert.ToDouble throws System.FormatException for some unknown reason

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I am parsing an xml file and I am trying to assign a value which I is read from xml file into a double variable.

here is what my code looks like:

```
double someDouble = Convert.ToDouble(someString);
```

problem here is, when executing this line of code, i get

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

When I debug, i see that the value of `someString` is "45.00000000" in the "Locals" view.

As far as I know [Convert.ToDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) supports such converting strings into double.

**NOTE**: just to be sure I also tried

```
double someDouble = Convert.ToDouble(someString.Trim('"'));
```

Comment: With current culture set to `en-US` the above code runs just fine. There's something else going on here. FWIW, exceptions are **never** thrown "for no reason".

Comment: Can you post the exact code you are using? There is no reason 45.000000 should be causing your a problem. Get rid of everything in your post, post your code, and the singular question you have.  Reference Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx

Comment: How are you assigning the value from the Xml element to the string someString?

Comment: @Ramhound: accepted answer (if not accepted now in 3 min) solved the problem so I'm not updating the question

Comment: @KevRitchie: accepted answer (if not accepted now in 3 min) solved the problem so I'm not updating the question

Comment: @AliVeli - The point of making your question more clear, is for future users, do what you want.  Your confusion about using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is a given if trying to mix and match cultures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works fine for me.

My psychic debugging skills tell me that you're running in a culture that uses `,` as the decimal separator.
Pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: For me it is surprising but this really worked. On MSDN it implicitly says that Convert.ToDouble accepts dot (.) as decimal seperator however it does not mention (neither implicitly nor explicitly) that you need to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote should work so long as the string being converted is actually a number.  Maybe there is a non-number somewhere in the string that you are not seeing.  That is the only thing that I can think of.

This won't solve your particular problem but I would recommend Double.TryParse instead of Convert.ToDouble.  You largely eliminate the chance that an exception will be thrown with Double.TryParse

Answer (score 1):

I would try calling Trim but without the parameter '"'.  Please try that and let me know the result.

Comment: the problem was culture (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as 2nd parameter to Convert.ToDouble)

Answer (score 0):

```
double someDouble = Convert.ToDouble("45.00000000"); //returns 45.0
```